How can I tell when the width of an inner element exceed that of the outer element
I need to find a way of finding out whether the inner child element's width exceeds that of the parent element. The following is my code.
<section class="anchor-links">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="content">
                <img decoding="async" class="left-arrow" src="http://staging.slattery.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2024/06/burgundy.svg">
                <div class="anchor-row">
                                        <div class="anchor-link">
                        <a href="#breakfast-and-sandwiches"><h3>Breakfast &amp; Sandwiches</h3></a>
                    </div>
                                        <div class="anchor-link">
                        <a href="#on-toast"><h3>On Toast</h3></a>
                    </div>
                                        <div class="anchor-link">
                        <a href="#egg-dishes"><h3>Egg</h3></a>
                    </div>
                                        <div class="anchor-link">
                        <a href="#morning-goods"><h3>Morning Goods</h3></a>
                    </div>
                                        <div class="anchor-link">
                        <a href="#extras"><h3>Extras</h3></a>
                    </div>
                                        <div class="anchor-link">
                        <a href="#sweet-choices"><h3>Sweet Choices</h3></a>
                    </div>
                                    </div>
                <img decoding="async" class="right-arrow" src="http://staging.slattery.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2024/06/burgundy.svg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

Essentially, the arrow images should only show to indicate when there are more options to show (when there is an overflow). Take a look at the images below. Image 1 requires no arrows because the menu does not overflow whereas image 2 will need the arrows as the image overflows.
image 1 - no arrows needed
image 2 - arrows needed
Thank you in advance
I tried the following code
if(document.querySelector('.page-id-1065') || document.querySelector('.page-id-1801')) {
    console.log('Correct page')
    const parentElement = document.querySelector('.anchor-links .content');
    const listElement = document.querySelector('.anchor-links .content .anchor-row');

    // Check if the list exceeds the parent element's width
    if (listElement.scrollWidth > parentElement.scrollWidth) {
        console.log('The list exceeds the width of its parent!');
    } else {
        console.log('The list fits within the parent element.');
    }
}

It gave the else outcome both times.

It’s not suitable to use scrollwidth on parent element because that includes content that is scrolled off the screen.

You can maybe try using getBoundingClientRect().width to get width of each child element and their sum and compare it with the wrapper one

const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
const browserHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

console.log("Pencere Yüksekliği:", windowHeight);
console.log("Tarayıcı Yüksekliği:", browserHeight);

// İç öğenin genişliğinin ana öğeyi aşıp aşmadığını kontrol etme
function checkOverflow(innerElement, outerElement) {
    const innerWidth = innerElement.scrollWidth; // İç öğenin tam genişliği
    const outerWidth = outerElement.clientWidth; // Ana öğenin görünür genişliği

    if (innerWidth > outerWidth) {
        console.log("İç öğe, ana öğeyi aşıyor.");
    } else {
        console.log("İç öğe, ana öğeye sığıyor.");
    }
}

// Örnek kullanım:
const innerElement = document.querySelector('.inner-child'); // İç öğe
const outerElement = document.querySelector('.outer-parent'); // Ana öğe

checkOverflow(innerElement, outerElement);

enter code here


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
